# Is there a way to force talkback to announce usage hints when a video is playing?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am developing a video player android-app. When video is paused, usage hints like "double tap to activate button" are announced properly but **when video is playing these hints are not announced by talkback.**

For example:
Announcement for seek forward button when video is paused = "Seek forward button. Double tap to activate" 
Same announcement button when video is playing = "Seek forward button"
(How to perform the action is not announced)

Is there a way to force talkback to announce hints for better accessibility?

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839403/pause-or-stop-talkback-voice-during-audio-recording-in-android)

Comment: Any text added via accessiblityEvent.addText(some_string) is being ignored by talkback when video is playing. It is only announcing content Description.

Comment: I had check-in Netflix app when I am playing video then some time forward button announcement is missed. make sure to include talkback setting in player also.